# Gamma Distribution with poisson rate

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

I'm not really sure whether this is gamma distribution or not. But I found similar question in Gamma Distribution chapter. From my perspective, we need to find the lambda first, which I think it supposed to be 2/10 = 1/5 since it happens 2 per ten years. And I think we're asked to find the expectation but I'm not sure and I don't know how.

```
Suppose that, on the Richter scale, earthquakes of magnitude 5.5 or higher 
have probability 0.01 of damaging certain types of brides. Suppose that such 
intense earthquakes occur at a Poisson rate of 2 per ten years. How many years 
is a bridge of this type expected to last in average?
```

So here I am guys. I hope you guys want to help me since I already give it all what I know. Thank you guys for your kindness.

Comment: This kind of problem is related to the thinning of Poisson process, but you may not need to actually use those properties in it. Let $T_i$ be the time for the $i$-th earthquake happen. We know that it has a gamma distribution with expectation $i/\lambda$. From the given information we know that $\lambda = 2/10 = 1/5$ (per year) as what you calculated. Now let $M$ be the number of earthquakes (Bernoulli trials) needed to damage the bridge, then it follows a geometric distribution, and the life time of the bridge is given as $T_M$. Now find the expectation by law of total expectation.

Comment: Hm, I still don't know how to solve the question. Can you help me more?@BGM

Comment: I have basically outlined the whole idea about the problem. You need to be more specific which part you are stucked.

Comment: How do we calculate the expectation by law of total expectation?@BGM

Comment: $E[T_M] = E[E[T_M|M]]$

Comment: Bro, so here what I can find out until now. we know that the lambda is 1/5 and in order to find the number of earthquake, I multiply 1/5 with 0.01, so the number of earthquake is 1/500 per year. And then following the geometric random variables, we find the life time of the bridge Tm by E(X) = 1/p = 1/0.01 = 100 years. So using the formula of gamma distribution, E(x) = r/lambda = 100 divided 1/500 which is equal to 500000 years. But I'm not sure whether it's true or not. @BGM

Comment: Is it true? @BGM

Comment: you have divided $0.01$ two times which is duplicated.

Comment: So what the answer should be bro? @BGM

Comment: I really need your help @BGM. No one can help me except you :(.

Comment: Please give me the answer sir, I've tried my best, I spent a few hours to understand this problem, yet hardwork didn't pay off.@BGM

Comment: $E[E[T_M|M]] = E[M/\lambda]$. And you can to continue.